# Change ImageButton image source inside ItemTemplate in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have `ImageButton` Inside `ItemTemplate` in `GridView` I want to change Image Url "Image source" based on condition that I have prepared before. In short when I click on the ImageButton, change it's image source "For the imageButton" based on the condition I have. Here is the code I have below:

ASP.NET GridView code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" BorderStyle="None"  GridLines="None" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="photo_id" HeaderText="photo_id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="photo_id"  ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"/>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="photo_path" SortExpression="photo_path">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("photo_path") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="container-md">
                    <div class="container">
                <asp:Image ID="Image8" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("photo_path") %>' CssClass="mx-auto d-block - responsive"/>
                         <div class="centered">
                             <asp:ImageButton ID="img_like" CssClass="os" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/like.png" OnClick="img_like_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
                         </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_id" HeaderText="user_id" SortExpression="user_id"  ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="photo_likes" HeaderText="photo_likes" SortExpression="photo_likes"  ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind "C#" With the If Statement condition:

```
protected void img_like_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;

        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

        if (isPhotoLiked(Convert.ToInt32(gvr.Cells[0])))
        {
            // CHANGE IMAGE TO FILLED HEART IF TRUE
        } else
        {
            // CHANGE IMAGE TO EMPTY HEART IF FALSE
        }
    }
```

The method that generates the condition if you need it:

```
public bool isPhotoLiked(int photoId)
    {
        bool isLiked = false;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=DESKTOP-N1LLATD\\SQLEXPRESS;database=final;integrated security=sspi");
        string sql = "select isLiked from Likes where photo_id=@photo_id";
        SqlCommand cmd_add = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd_add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo_id", photoId);
        SqlDataReader read;
        con.Open();
        read = cmd_add.ExecuteReader();
        if (read.HasRows)
        {
            if (read.Read())
            {
                isLiked = Convert.ToBoolean(read["isLiked"].ToString());
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        return isLiked;
    }
```

Comment: I would use a ````GridViewRowCommand```` and then inside the row command you can access the current ````GridViewRow```` and use the ````FindControl()```` to get your ImageButton and update it's ImageUrl.

Comment: Also, depending on if the Reader ````HasRows```` you may never close your connection. I'd update to have a ````Using```` statement so it will auto-close.